# wrong data type in mysql for grails byte[] property

Tags: mysql, grails, types

I have an application which is trying to save a photo to the database. I've created a grails domain class with a byte[] property and this was working well when using HSQLDB (the default in grails). However, when I changed the database to MySQL I ended up getting the following error:

```
Data truncation: Data too long for column 'photo' at row 1
```

I then had a look at the schema and found that the byte[] was being created as a TINYBLOB field, which was causing the error.

How can I specify that this property should correspond to a BLOB/LONGBLOB type in the database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to manage that by adding a `mapping` closure a bit like this:

```
static mapping = {
    photo type: "binary" // or "blob"?
}
```

Documentation is here: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/type.html

Hibernate types are here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-types-basictypes

There's also a `sqlType` property, which I believe refers to the underlying database type, rather than hibernate's database agnostic type abstractions:

```
static mapping = {
    photo column: "photo_data", sqlType: "blob"
}
```

Documentation for this is here:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

Comment: Thanks for that. The second method, explicitly specifying the 'sqlType' worked. The first method, setting the type to 'binary' still resulted in the column being a TINYINT type (and giving the same errors as before).

Comment: You may find that the field stop working against other databases, as you're bypassing Hibernate's type abstractions, but that may not matter. Does it work against HSQL?

Comment: It happens we just hit this exact problem and so I can answer my own question: specifying `sqlType='blob'` does not work in HSQL. It fails with `ERROR hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  - Wrong data type: BLOB in statement [create table image (id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1), version bigint not null, data blob]`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a constraint with maxSize for that field.

```
static constraints = {
    photo(maxSize: 102400) // 100Kb
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `application.properties` file. I was using `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` and this is only for springBoot version 1.x.

Now you can use `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl-auto=update` for springBoot version 2.x. I hope this solves your problem.